# How to combine results of a for loop, inside a function, in to a character vector?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, concatenation

```
my_function <- function(A,B,C,D,E) {
for (event in c(A,B,C,D,E)){
    if (event %in% c(A,E)) print(paste0(event, "foo"))
    if (event %in% c(B,C,D)) print(paste0(event, "bar"))
  }
}

my_function(45, 34, 23, 213, 134)
[1] "45foo"
[1] "34bar"
[1] "23bar"
[1] "213bar"
[1] "134foo"
```

The function returns 5 character vectors of length 1. I would like the function to return one vector of length 5 - in the order passed by in the arguments (A>B>C>D>E)

Comment: You function doesn't return anything, it just prints. Do `result = my_function(45, 34, 23, 213, 134)`, then see that `result` is `NULL`. I assume you do want to return something, not just print a result, but I want to check to be sure.

Comment: @Gregor you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function actually doesn't return anything, it just prints the statements. 
If you want to return something, this is an option:

```
my_function <- function(A,B,C,D,E) {
  return(sapply(c(A,B,C,D,E),function(x){
    if(x %in% c(A,E)) return(paste0(x,"foo"))
    if(x %in% c(B,C,D)) return(paste0(x,"bar"))
  }))
}
```